# Netbeans Drag and Drop: checking the location where an image is dropped

Tags: java, image, netbeans, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a drag and drop environment in Netbeans where three images are displayed along with three texts describing the images. Below is an example:
[image: Example image]

So, I want to check that the right image has been dropped at the right text location. Is there any way this could be done? Some method that can getDropLocation when mouse is released?

Comment: It seems a little too on the nose. But are you just looking for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.TransferSupport.html#getDropLocation--